# SqLite on Windows Mobile 6 emulator

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-mobile, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite on my mobile application. I can add the reference to `System.Data.SQLite.dll` but I can not get the `SQLite.Interop.066.DLL` dll copied to my emulator. It shows this error

> Not enough storage is available to process this command.

How can I test my application on emulator?

Answer (score 0):

It is an emulator. Why do you have so many programs installed on it?

Windows-Mobile has limited RAM that it can work with.

Basically, you'll have to close or uninstall programs until you have enough room to run your application.

Comment: I do not have anything installed on my emulator. when i remove the reference and install. it works fine.